# How can I access new window elements in cypress?

Tags: javascript, node.js, automation, cypress

[image]

I am testing `Azure Login`.

In this situation, it opens a new window. I am trying to access this element which is in new window and the exact url of new window is unknown.

[image]

I am trying this below solution but can't connect them.

```
export const loginWithAzure = (email, password) => {

  cy.window().then(win => {
    cy.stub(win, 'open').as('open')
  })

  //on test window
  clickButtonByText('Azure Login');
  cy.get('@open').should('have.been.calledOnce');

  //------How to connect the logic------------

  // on new window
  getElement('[name=loginfmt]').typeIfNotEmpty(email).should('have.value', email);
  clickButtonByText('Next');
  getElement('[name=passwd]').typeIfNotEmpty(password).should('have.value', password);
  clickButtonByText('Sign in');

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cypress is not able to interact with other windows or tabs. This is an [inherit trade-off with Cypress](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/trade-offs#Multiple-browsers-open-at-the-same-time).

Logging in using OAuth providers is still possible though. Generally this involves requesting the token yourself using `cy.request()` and Cypress will install it into your browser for you. This means there's no need to interact with the login page generally.

Good - Test login is much more stable requesting the tokens and skipping the login screen.

Bad - You need knowledge of OAuth to setup

[Auth0 Cypress recipe](https://auth0.com/blog/end-to-end-testing-with-cypress-and-auth0/#Writing-tests-using-Cypress-Login-Command)

[Cypress's own recipe for handling OAuth requests](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/blob/master/examples/logging-in__single-sign-on/cypress/e2e/logging-in-single-sign-on-spec.cy.js)